# How to show locations of friends on map near by 20 km from user current location in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, apple-maps

I want to get locations of my friends near by me within 20km.App should track my current location and when i want to search for friends within 20km,It should show All my friends location on map.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
```

}

Comment: how will you store your friends location ?

Comment: I am getting from Addressbook

Comment: i am also asking same question of Mr. T. because how you will know which friend is where? You need to fetch your friend location first and store it any variable and compare your location with your friend location. SO you will get friends near by 20 KMs

Comment: For example,I have friends locations in NSARRAY *Longitude,*Latitude;

Comment: then,how to compare within 20km region.

Comment: My problem is to compare in specific region,not getting locations.So,kindly tell me what to do with it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into

`-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;`

and use this to get your current location:

```
  [locations lastObject];
```

and to get distance use this:

```
  distanceFromLocation:
```

Comment: For example,i have 10 friends who location is near to me in 20km. So how write code for it.Thanks

Comment: I donot need there location. I need how to search locations of friends within 20km from my location.

Comment: i can write the whole code for you, but you will not learn anything from it. Start with adding a simple mapkit to your app and generate your current location on the map.

Comment: Sir,i have done to get my location,but problem is that,I want to compare my friends locations within 20km from my current location,if someone location matchs then it should return me success.

Comment: For example,I have locations in Array,not getting from Addressbook

Comment: if you have done that part, then please add the code to your question.

Comment: locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: '- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}'

Comment: not as a commment. Add it your question